# Confused with Postgres COALESCE retuning 'null'

Tags: postgresql, null-coalescing

A postgres table contains a column with the data type:

`test_score character varying(10)`

The column may contain null values or numeric.

| SQL | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `select COALESCE( test_score, '0' )` | `''` (blank) |
| `select COALESCE( test_score::numeric, 0 )` | `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""` |
| `select COALESCE( test_score::numeric, 0 )` | `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""` |
| `select CASE WHEN test_score = '' THEN 0 ELSE test_score::numeric END` | works `0` (intended result) |
| `select CASE WHEN test_score IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE test_score::numeric END` | `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""` |

In Oracle terms, I want `NVL( TO_NUMBER( test_score ), 0 )`, which would always work (assume test_score holds a number).

What is the correct way to use COALESCE in this scenario?

Comment: You can't. `COALESCE` is designed to work on `NULL` values, and `test_score` is not `NULL`, it's an empty string.

Comment: `select coalesce(nullif(trim(''), '')::numeric, 0);`. In your case `select coalesce(nullif(trim(test_score), '')::numeric, 0);`, to catch `test_score` values of `'  '` of 1 or more empty spaces.

Comment: Part of your confusion may be because ["oracle currently treats a character value with a length of zero as null"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Nulls.html); Postgres does not.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver +1. Put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: "*the column may contain null values or numeric*" - then why are you storing them as `character varying(10)`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way I know of doing this is:

`select coalesce(nullif(trim(test_score), '')::numeric, 0);`

Using functions from here [Conditional Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html).

Where `trim` removes any empty spaces from `test_score` and gets the value to `''` in the case where there is no numeric value and then `nullif` converts the value to `NULL` which is cast to `numeric` which in turn `coalesce` converts to `0`.